# How to pause the video if I press the Windows a.k.a. Start button just like how this code pauses the video when a new tab is opened?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any utility or method in js which can pause the video playback when either the windows button or the taskbar is pressed?

```
<html>
    <title>Video</title>
    <body>
        <video id="video" controls>
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         </video>

    <script>
        var focused = true;
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function () {
      foo = !foo;
      if (!foo)
        document.getElementById("video").pause();
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The script element must be within the head or body elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is very specific like pausing the playback when "Windows" key is pressed you can use the solution suggested by @Ashok Arora.
This solution will help you achieve a more general playback pause and play.
Whenever the user's focus moves out of the current page the blur event will be triggered and the video will be paused and whenever the user's focus comes back to the page the video will start playing back.
This works for your requirement of Windows key or taskbar being pressed as well as for a lot of other scenarios where the user goes away from the page.

Since it is a webpage there is a high possibility that the page may not be viewed only on a windows machine but also on a variety of other platforms. So I would recommend a more general approach.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Video Playback</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video height="400" width="550" controls id="video">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
    </video>
    <script>
        let video = document.getElementById("video");
        window.addEventListener('blur',pauseVideo);
        function pauseVideo(){
            video.pause();
        }
        window.addEventListener('focus',playVideo);
        function playVideo(){
            video.play();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way.

This answer uses JS/jQuery and a basic understanding of key presses.

Keypresses is like a signal, so everytime you press a key, it gives off a particular numerical signal that the key was pressed.

To test keypresses, check [HERE](https://keycode.info/).

```
$(function() {
    var e = $.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 91;
    $('item').trigger(e);
});
```

This is the jQuery function which can be executed when keypress 91 is detected.

Now that magic number keypress 91 corresponds to the OS key or "Windows Key".

Comment: How should I add this code in the above HTML? Just wrap this inside the <script> tag?That's it to make this accomplish my objective?

Comment: I'm a newbie to jQuery. Could you tell me how to add this code in the HTML? Would be great if the complete code is given :) Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, since jQuery is also javascript, we need to write it inside <script> tag but there's a small change. It would be like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">  code goes here </script>` , in this script jQuery will be sourced.